# Nexus 7 installation: PPA error

Tags: system-installation, ppa, tablet, nexus-7

I'm following [this Ubuntu wiki guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) to install on Nexus 7.

When I add the PPA and update it gives me a failed to fetch 404 error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Note though, that that PPA does not have Saucy packages.

Answer (score 1):

As the wiki page tells you it's no longer maintained.

And if you visit its Launchpad page, you'll see that it [only has a full package compliment](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-nexus7/+archive/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/+packages) for Precise and Quantal.

Project is dead. You can try to hgack around it by downloading the packages directly from Launchpad but IMO you're putting your devices in unneccessary risk.